# How to display R^2 in caption of a figure?

Tags: graphics

I need to add R^2 in the caption of a figure.

Here is the code:

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
    \usepackage{setspace}% for\doublespacing
    \usepackage{indentfirst}% for indent the first line
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{textalpha} 
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
     \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
    \usepackage{xltabular} 
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \begin{document}

    
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics{Correlation.jpg}
    \caption{The correlation between behavior test results and corticosterone (CORT). A. Correlation between sucrose preference and baseline CORT in the LT cohort (R2 = 0.06, \textit{F} (1, 75) = 4.86, \textit{p} < 0.05). B. Correlation between sucrose preference and recovery CORT in the LT cohort (R2 = 0.12, \textit{F }(1, 75) = 9.93, \textit{p} < 0.05). C. Correlation between sociability ratio (R2 = 0.16, \textit{F} (1, 75) = 14.72, \textit{p} < 0.01) and recovery CORT in the LT cohort. LSR line: Least Squares Regression Line.}
    \label{Correlation.jpg}
   \end{center}
   \end{figure}
   \end{document}
```

my ideal result should be the R with superscript 2 in the photo:

[image]

Comment: Does math mode work? `$R^2 = 0.06$`; same for the other entries

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use a `center` *environment* inside a LaTeX float, as doing so creates additional, generally unwelcome whitespace padding. Instead, use a single `\centering` *command*.

Comment: Even more off-topic:`$R^2$ is **not** a correlation coefficient. Its name is "coefficient of determination", i.e., it's a goodness-of-fit measure. How about calling the relationship shown in the graphs a "fitted linear relationship" instead? E.g., "Fitted linear relationship between sucrose preference and baseline CORT", etc?

Comment: Oh thank you for the comment. I would change that.

Comment: You mnight also add an optional empty "short caption", even if you aren't doing a list of figures.  Some things just look ugly in the aux file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, as I commented:

and use mathmode all the way, i.e. drop `\textit` etc.

[image]

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[draft]{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
%    \usepackage{setspace}% for\doublespacing
%    \usepackage{indentfirst}% for indent the first line
%    \usepackage{longtable}
%    \usepackage{textalpha} 
%    \usepackage{ragged2e}
     \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
%    \usepackage{xltabular} 
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \begin{document}

    
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics{Correlation.jpg}
    \caption{The correlation between behavior test results and corticosterone (CORT). A. Correlation between sucrose preference and baseline CORT in the LT cohort ($R^2 = 0.06$, \textit{F} (1, 75) = 4.86, \textit{p} < 0.05). B. Correlation between sucrose preference and recovery CORT in the LT cohort (R2 = 0.12, \textit{F }(1, 75) = 9.93, \textit{p} < 0.05). C. Correlation between sociability ratio (R2 = 0.16, \textit{F} (1, 75) = 14.72, \textit{p} < 0.01) and recovery CORT in the LT cohort. LSR line: Least Squares Regression Line.}
    \label{Correlation.jpg}
   \end{center}
   \end{figure}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!